# Is it possible to update a ion-picker along with its values?

Tags: ionic4

I have asked a similar question about this before, but now the main problem has changed:

I have an ion-picker with two rows, and the values of the 2nd row change completely depending on what you choose in the 1st row. Now I can change the values that are received when an option is selected, but the picker doesn't update, so even though other values are being used, the old ones are still being displayed, and that's a pretty big problem.

In the answer I received in the earlier question, I was told that there's a function called forceUpdate(), but when I tried it, it changed nothing.
I was told that this could still be in development and maybe even get removed in the near future, but I need to know if there's a way to update the ion-picker now or not.

**Here's the code for the ion-picker:**

```
async showJetPicker(id) {
    if (this.disabledis[id - 6] !== true) {
    const opts: PickerOptions = {
      cssClass: 'academy-picker',
      buttons: [
        ...
      ],
      columns: [
        {
          name: '1st row',
          options:  this.convertColumns(this.pickerbois[id].options[0])
        },
        {
          name: '2nd row',
          options:  this.convertColumns(this.pickerbois[id].options[1])
        }
      ]
    };
    const picker = await this.pickerCtrl.create(opts);
    picker.addEventListener('ionPickerColChange', async (event: any) => {
      const data = event.detail;
      const colSelectedIndex = data.selectedIndex;
      const colOptions = data.options;
      if (colSelectedIndex < 2) {
        picker.columns[1].options = this.convertColumns(this.pickerbois[id].options[colSelectedIndex + 1]);
        picker.forceUpdate();   //Here it should update the picker
      }
    });
    this.picker_cancer = picker;
    picker.present();
    }
  }
```

Comment: can you create an example of what you have so far so that people can easily try to help? The technique you are using is an undocumented feature so unless you make it easy for people to try out some code you have a low chance of finding somebody who already knows the answer from experience. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

please try below, which fixed mine.

```js
async showJetPicker(id) {
  if (this.disabledis[id - 6] !== true) {
  const opts: PickerOptions = {
    cssClass: 'academy-picker',
    buttons: [
      ...
    ],
    columns: [
      {
        name: '1st row',
        options:  this.convertColumns(this.pickerbois[id].options[0])
      },
      {
        name: '2nd row',
        options:  this.convertColumns(this.pickerbois[id].options[1])
      }
    ]
  };
  const picker = await this.pickerCtrl.create(opts);
  picker.addEventListener('ionPickerColChange', async (event: any) => {
    const data = event.detail;
    const colSelectedIndex = data.selectedIndex;
    const colOptions = data.options;
    let temColumns;
    if (colSelectedIndex < 2) {
      //picker.columns[1].options = this.convertColumns(this.pickerbois[id].options[colSelectedIndex + 1]);
      //picker.columns[1].options = this.convertColumns(this.pickerbois[id].options[colSelectedIndex + 1]);
      
      temColumns = this.convertColumns(this.pickerbois[id].options[colSelectedIndex + 1]);        
      picker.columns[1].options = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(temColumns));
      
      picker.forceUpdate();   //Here it should update the picker
    }
  });
  this.picker_cancer = picker;
  picker.present();
  }
}
```

Comment: ```picker.forceUpdate();```   not working in 2023 , ```ionic 5```